# jQuery | Selecting Class out of multiple having specific text in span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following piece of code implemented on website.

"time" class stores the time slots and 
"cost" class stores the price

I want to select that "abc" class wherein - 
"time" class must be between 06:00 and 12:00  AND then 
 between 06:00 - 12:00, we need to look for highest "cost" value under span

I am able to select the timeslots and the highest cost but not able to combine both functions.

```js
// Selection of Time Slots

var timeSlots = $(".master > .abc > .time > span").text();
var timeArray = timeSlots.split('NonStop');

var resultArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
  var bar = /(^06|^07|^08|^09|^10|^11)/;
  if (bar.test(timeArray[i])) {
  //  console.log("found time");
    resultArray.push(timeArray[i]);
  }
};


// Selection of Highest Cost

var priceCount = $(".master > .abc > .cost > label").text();
var priceArray = priceCount.split('₹');
var myFilterArray = priceArray.filter(Boolean);
var highestPrice = myFilterArray[0];
for (var a = 1; a < myFilterArray.length; a++) {
  if (myFilterArray[a] > highestPrice) {
    highestPrice = myFilterArray[a];
  }
}
console.log(highestPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="time"><span>06:05 NonStop</span></div>
    <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹2,987</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>03:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹4,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>07:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹8,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>08:15 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹1,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>15:45 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹9,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to achieve the goal. You actually do not require to have different methods one can do for you.

```js
// Selection of Time Slots

var price = $(".master > .abc > .cost > label");

var timeSlots = $(".master > .abc > .time > span").text();
var timeArray = timeSlots.split('NonStop');
var highestPrice = 0;
var hPriceStr = "";
var resultArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
  var bar = /(^06|^07|^08|^09|^10|^11)/;
  if (bar.test(timeArray[i])) {
    var sp = $(price[i]).text().split("₹")[1];
    var tempPrice = Number(sp.replace(",", ""));
    if (highestPrice < tempPrice) {
      highestPrice = tempPrice;
      hPriceStr = sp;
    }
    resultArray.push(timeArray[i]);
  }
};



var selector = ".master > .abc > .cost > label:contains('₹" + hPriceStr + "')"
$(selector).css("background", "#ff9900");
//console.log(highestPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="time"><span>06:05 NonStop</span></div>
    <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹2,987</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>03:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹4,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>07:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹8,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>08:15 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹1,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>15:45 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹9,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ullas Hunka the expectation is 8,976 as this is the highest price in time slots between 06:00 - 12:00. 9, 9976 is the cost of time slot 15:45, I do not want to look beyond 12:00

Answer (score 0):

i think the best practice to use in this case is: When rendering the html, add an attribute to span element.

example:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="time"><span intime="0305">03:05 NonStop</span></div>
    <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹4,976</span><label></div>
</div>
```

then

```
var timeSlots = $(".master > .abc > .time > span").each(function(i, e){
    var time = $(this).attr('intime');
    if( parseInt(time) > 0600 && parseInt(time) < 1200)
    {
        resultArray.push( $(this).val() );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guy  i think you can used array object  and  light weight code

```js
var arrdata = [];

$.each($(".abc"), function (index, data) {
       arrdata.push(
       {
         index : index ,
         time: $(".abc:eq("+index+") > .time  span").text() , 
         price: $(".abc:eq("+index+") > .cost span").text().split("₹")[1] 
       });                             
      
});
var maxdata= [];
$.each(arrdata, function (index, data) {
  if (index === 0 )   
  {
    maxdata = arrdata[index]; 
  
  }
  else 
  {
     if (arrdata[index].price > maxdata.price )
     {
      maxdata = arrdata[index];
     
     }
   }
 
})
console.log(maxdata);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="time"><span>06:05 NonStop</span></div>
    <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹2,987</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>03:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹4,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
      <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>15:45 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹9,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>07:05 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹8,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
      
     <div class="abc">
      <div class="time"><span>08:15 NonStop</span></div>
      <div class="cost"><label class><span>₹1,976</span><label></div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

This code  can help you